# What is the professional/optimum way to manage JSON data based on URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

As the title suggests, I am unsure of the best way to manage the data that is pulled from a number of different URL's.

I have a website that I can pull JSON data from a bunch of different URL's.

As an example: I have a page with lots of posts relating to a group with a URL like the following:

```
url.com/group/posts
```

I can call the data with the following snippet:

```
$(function(){

    var url = ('/api/group/posts');

    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

And this returns the data fine. However I need a dynamic way of calling that URL without using a static string.

I was thinking initially to use something like the following:

```
var url = ('/api'+String(window.location.pathname));
```

But I run into problems when I want to call some data that isn't necessarily the same as the URL.

I could always use a bunch of 'if statements' to query if it's a relevant page but this feels like a messy solution.

I had another thought of having the relevant URL/Path inside the specific pages DOM, using perhaps a 'data' attribute but this also seems messy and an exposure of data.

What is the industry convention or 'Best Practice' for managing URL relevant JSON data that isn't always specifically relevant to the URLs Pathname?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: But I run into problems when I want to call some data that isn't necessarily the same as the URL. what does it mean can u explain ?

Comment: For example if the data can be pulled from the following URL: 'api/group/posts/top' but the actual URL is: 'url.com/group/posts/highest-rated'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the current path of the window would work nicely if it does match the data URL most of the time. Just make an entry in the URLMappings object to keep track of any exceptions to the rule. This way you can keep it all in one place.

```
$(function() {

    // Create an object to keep track of any exceptions.
    var URLMappings = {
        '/api/group/posts/highest-rated': '/api/group/posts/top',
        '/api/group/posts/lowest-rated' : '/api/group/posts/bottom',
        '/api/group/posts/most-viewed'  : '/api/group/posts/active'
    };

    // Get the URL by using the path name of the window.
    var URL = '/api' + window.location.pathname;

    // Check if an exception exists for the current URL.
    if (typeof URLMappings[URL] != 'undefined') {
        URL = URLMappings[URL];
    }

    // Get the data.
    $.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: This seems like an effective way to handle the URL's Thank you.